# Calculating the sup and inf of the expression $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+k}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}-n}$, where $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to calculate supremum and infimum of a set given by:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+k}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}-n}$$

for $n, k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$

So, I see that: $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+k}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}-n}= \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2k}{n^2}}-1}$

I know for sure that the expression is bigger when $\frac{k}{n^2}$ is smaller because there are 2 of these in denominator and just one in nominator. So I know that I will get:

- superemum for $k = 1$, $n \implies \infty$
- infimum for $n = 1$, $k \implies \infty$

I get:

- INF = $\lim_{k \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+k}-1}{\sqrt{1+2k}-1} = \frac{1}{2}$
- SUP = $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+2}-n} = ?$

And that's it. I cant find that limit. If I just take $n^2$ out, I get $\frac{0}{0}$. If I make it a difference of squares I get $\infty - \infty$ in nominator.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that your numbers can also be written as
$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{k}{n^2}\Bigl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2k}{n^2}}+1\Bigr)}
{\dfrac{2k}{n^2}\Bigl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac{k}{n^2}}+1\Bigr)}
=
\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2k}{n^2}}+1}
{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{k}{n^2}}+1}
$$
If you take $k=rn^2$, you get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{1+2r}+1}{\sqrt{1+r}+1}
$$
whose limit for $r\to\infty$ is $\sqrt{2}/2$.

Can you prove this is the supremum?

If you take $k=0$ (I know it's invalid, but it's certainly a starting point with the new expression, isn't it?), you get $1/2$. Can you prove this is the infimum?

Comment: And could it be done just on n? Is it possible? Because it looked easy at first sight and then I just couldn't get the limit in any way.

Comment: @theboyboy Well, you have two parameters, you can't just fix one of them.

Comment: Why not? I described in my question that I can see that for a fixed k = 1 I get the supremum by finding the limit of n in $\infty$.

Comment: @theboyboy For $k=1$ the limit is not $\infty$, but $1/2$.

Comment: I know, I mean that I look for a limit (value) of that expression with n going to infinity.

Comment: @theboyboy And it leads nowhere for the purpose of your exercise.

Comment: "So, I see that: $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+k}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}-n}= \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2k}{n^2}}-1}$

I know for sure that the expression is bigger when $\frac{k}{n^2}$ is smaller because there are 2 of these in denominator and just one in nominator. So I know that I will get:

 - superemum for $k = 1$, $n \implies \infty$
 - infimum for $n = 1$, $k \implies \infty$ " The limit for n = 1 and k in $\infty$ came out to be $\frac{1}{2}$ which is right. So it clearly leads me somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First we rewrite the ratio as
$$R(n,k):=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+k}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}-n} = \frac{1 \cdot (\sqrt{n^2+2k}+n)}{2 \cdot (\sqrt{n^2+k}+n)} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2k}{n^2}}+1}{2(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}+1)}$$

Note that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2k}{n^2}}+1}{2(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}+1)} > \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}+1}{2(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}+1)} = \frac 12 \tag1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty, k=1}\text{LHS of }(1)=\frac{1}{2}
$$

On the other hand
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2k}{n^2}}+1}{2(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}+1)} < \frac{\sqrt{2+\frac{2k}{n^2}}+\sqrt 2}{2(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}+1)} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \tag2
$$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty, k=n^2} \text{ LHS of (2) } = \frac{\sqrt{1+2n^2}+1}{2(\sqrt{1+n^2}+1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+2}+\frac 1n}{2(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+1}+\frac 1n)} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}.
$$

Therefore $\inf R(n,k)=\frac 12, \sup R(n,k)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

Comment: Could you tell me how did you get this: $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n^2+2}-n} = \frac{1 \cdot (\sqrt{n^2+2}+n)}{2 \cdot (\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)} $$ ?

Comment: Just cross multiply and you'll see.

Comment: Also, I don't think the answer is right

Comment: I should get $\sqrt{2}/2$

Comment: OK it's the same technique anyway. See egreg's answer.

Comment: I don't think that's the same technique. I tried cross multiplying and it got me nowhere.

Comment: I just edited. You'll see.

Comment: Can it be done just on n? I mean without $\frac{k}{n}$, as you did it before (when it was wrong, but it used more usual approach than egreg's solution).

Comment: Without $k/n$ you only get the inf.  You have to let $k/n^2$ to approach $\infty$ to get the sup. I just updated again.